# Al intentar acceder desde la red de datos móviles a mi aplicacion web, recibo un error 403 Forbidden

Tags: nginx, cache, vps, error-403

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con front end en React, back-end en Spring Boot y utilizando Nginx como servidor web. He configurado mi firewall (UFW) para abrir los puertos necesarios y permitir todos los rangos de direcciones IP. Sin embargo, me encuentro con un problema: cuando accedo a la aplicación desde un teléfono celular conectado a través de Wi-Fi, todo funciona bien, pero al intentar acceder desde la red de datos móviles, recibo un error 403 Forbidden. Curiosamente, después de limpiar el caché del navegador, puedo acceder sin problemas. ¿Alguien ha experimentado este tipo de comportamiento antes? ¿Qué podría estar causando este problema y cómo podría solucionarlo para garantizar un acceso sin problemas desde cualquier conexión? La misma esta alojada en un VPS Ubuntu.